# Can one have separate Apple ID passwords for consumer and developer services?

Tags: ios, apple-id

I have Apple ID email set in my iPhone/iPad and in the iOS Developer program (paid). I have an Apple ID that I currently use for both consumer services and an Apple Developer Program (paid).

Can I have separate passwords for the consumer and developer services provided by Apple?

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:** No.

I assume that by "my password in the iPhone/iPad" you mean the Apple ID you use for your consumer needs, in which case, no. Your Apple ID has one password used throughout, for both consumer *and* developer needs.

---

**Bonus answer:** If you truly wish wish to separate your consumer services from your developer services, then you have no option but to create a separate Apple ID (representing your company or your "developer brand" etc.). There's no way to "transfer" a paid enrollment, however if money is an issue you can just wait it out cancel auto-renewal (if at all).

As for the matter of transferring your apps from one Apple ID to another, Apple provides official documentation on this [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html). An excerpt:

> You move apps out of your organization’s catalog of apps by
>   transferring an app to another organization or by deleting the app.
>   You want to transfer an app when you’ve sold the app to another
>   developer or you want to move it to another iTunes Connect
>   organization. You want to delete an app when you’re ready to retire an
>   app and there’s no chance you will want to offer it for sale or
>   download in the future or to reuse the app name.
>
> You can transfer the ownership of an app to another developer without
>   removing the app from the store. The app retains its reviews and
>   ratings during and after the transfer, and users continue to have
>   access to future updates. There’s no limit to the number of apps you
>   can transfer, but each app needs to be transferred individually.

On an informal note, my personal opinion is that this strict delineation is not necessary, unless, of course, you are contractually obligated to do so.

Comment: Thank you Vatsal.  In this case, how difficult is to change the iOS Developer Apple ID (to a different email address) and different password? So that my consumer needs Apple ID is different from my developer needs ID?